# Making a copy of an image

Tags: python

I am supposed to create several functions for my python program, and each program requires me to work with a copy of an input image. Hence, I need to write img = image.copy() for every function in my code. However, when I run the code, I am returned an AttributeError saying "'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'. "

Given that I still have to include the statement img = image.copy() somewhere inside my function, how do I go about changing my code to remove this error?  Do I need to change the image into numpy array first before I can use copy()?

Code:

```
def func(image):
    img = image.copy() #error code appeared here
    np_img = np.array(image)
    rsize, csize = len(img), len(img[0]) #denoting the rows and columns of pixels of the image respectively
    (the rest of the code)
```

Error message: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: Hi ! If you want some help it'll be nice to copy us the full error message and the code you tried to run

Comment: Can you update your post accordingly and please copy the entire error message with an indication on which line the error occurred and also what arguments you passed to the function... Don't forget to format the code please

Comment: Post has been edited to include my code and the error message

Comment: how did you get the "image" argument ? it looks like image is a tuple

Comment: the image was already part of the skeleton file that i was given, so it is supposed to be an argument of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have to put `img=image.copy()` in your functions, the easiest way should be to flip the order of `np_img = np.array(image)` and the former line. I'm assuming that your argument `image` has not been converted into a numpy array prior to what we see here.

After that, you should change `img=image.copy()` to the appropriate variables.

That said, I think it's best to load the image as a numpy matrix right away before doing anything else. That way, you can make a copy before any of your functions, lowering each function's costs too.

Comment: I have switched the order of the 2 statements, but now I get ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,5,3) into shape (5,5) for the array line. How do I fix this error?

Comment: @fsfjbvndfislblvdv That's because your image is a colored image. the 5,5 refers to the row and column of your image, but there are three RGB channels for a colored image as well. Hope this gives you insight on what you need to do!